# Run a command before windows service starts

Tags: java, c++, windows, windows-services

I have a windows service running a java application. When I install this application on a share drive it takes ages to start. I decided i want to copy all the application jars and libs to a local path, and run it from there.
The problem is I can't find a clean way to do it. I understand i cannot run a batch script (to copy the files before starting the app) as a service. I don't want to create two services with dependancies on them and creating another java app just for copying the jars sounds and overkill for the problem.

Can you think if a nice way to do it? I thought maybe downloading a template of a generic windows service (I don't care what language, preferablly C\C++) and make it copy the jars\libs to local disk and then execute the regular service to run from there. If this is the write way, is there an equivilant of the exec linux system call in Windows? i don't want the startup executable to stay alive while the app is running.

Thanks in advance

Comment: True Windows executables have a "run from network" bit in their header, but your Java .jar's of course aren't Windows executables. That said, isn't the startup so slow because networking is started fairly late in the boot process?

Comment: no, i don't run the service on boot. even from idle state, when i start the service it takes alot of time to begin (sometimes the windows bar disappers and i get a notice that the service didn't start on time but then it appears as started).